# Shortcut super + t doesn't open the trash anymore

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

After a fresh install of Ubuntu16.04 (Xenial Xerus), shortcut combination <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> opening trash folder in Nautilus is no more present in comparison to Ubuntu 15.10,  *Wily Werewolf* (when holding the super key, it no more shows the "t" letter on the trash icon in the launcher, BUT it still shows as a possible shortcut on the reminder panel of general shortcuts).

Comment: That is weird. `Super` + `T` stills opens Trash for me in Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @edwinksl not on my system! (?) (16.04 as well)

Comment: @JacobVlijm Yeah, not sure what is going on to be honest. I also have a reasonably clean install of 16.04, so @antab should have been able to use `Super` + `T` too.

Comment: Hi antab, posted my answer. Please let me know if you manage.

Comment: @JacobVlijm according to [the sources](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~unity-team/unity/trunk/view/head:/shortcuts/StandaloneShortcuts.cpp#L103), you should have it enable. I'm not sure where are listed the dconf preferences in the sources.

Comment: @Braiam I'll try to find out. The keyboard shortcut didn't raise an error either, which should be the case I assume if it was set. Apparantly I am not the only one who is missing  the shortcut.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparantly not (I didn't even know it existed in earlier versions!), but you can create it in a jiffy:

Choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the command:

```
nautilus trash:///
```

Use <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> as shortcut and you're done :)

Comment: Yes it works, thank you (and the others for showing interest).